# xmlhttp POST isn't working

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to post transactions to server using a middleware client (it's called Cohesion). Below is my code (asp):

```
Dim xmlhttp 'As Object

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://server_ip/Databox-dr/CohesionConnect.asmx/GetHostReply", False

'using only http://server_ip/Databox-dr/CohesionConnect.asmx doesn't work, either

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "128"

xmlhttp.send "50000000000MSUF"

Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

The documentation I have (and that's all of it) is tellin me this:

HTTP POST
The following is a sample HTTP POST request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /DATABOX-DR/CohesionConnect.asmx/GetHostReply HTTP/1.1
Host: server_ip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

sTran=string



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://fidelityifs.com/webservices">string</string>
```

(length and string need to replaced with real values)

What am I doing wrong? How can I set the string length?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://server_ip/Databox-dr/CohesionConnect.asmx/GetHostReply", False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

tosend = "50000000000MSUF"
s = "sTran=" & tosend

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(s)

xmlhttp.send s
```

Comment: It didn't work... Can you recommend something to read that would maybe help with that? Thanks!

Comment: I believe this part is the response, so what you send, would not work:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://fidelityifs.com/webservices">string</string>

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work... All I get to see is a 500 0 0 in the IIS log. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Below are 2 IIS log entries, the first one is from another app that connects successfully, teh second is mine:

Comment: @MariusD 500 is a server error, that means it's getting your request and connected successfully, but doesn't like the data you are sending it (in this case `sTran=50000000000MSUF`) Unfortunately I don't know anything about the API you are using :(

Comment: I will play with that, I used their own app to build that string... Thanks again for your help!!